# android autofill ignores importantForAutofill="no"

Tags: android, forms, kotlin, autofill, android-textinputlayout

i have a form layout with multiple TextInputLayouts (containing a TextInputEditText).
Two of those field are used to input given- and familyname. Another field is the contact id ("Kontaktnummer" on the screenshots).
When i set focus to the given name field, android autofill suggests a name. If i tap on the autofill suggestion, it correctly fills given- and familyname fields.
However, it also fills the contact id field with the given name.
I have set importantForAutofill to no on the contact id field, without any effect. I have also set the correct autofill hints on the other two fields.

[image: pre autofill]

[image: wrong autofill]

Comment: Are you setting this on the `TextInputLayout` or the `TextInputEditText` itself? If it's on the layout, you probably need to use `noExcludeDescendants` instead (so the layout and all its children are marked as not important)

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations, as well as the one you mentioned, though none worked out for me.